# [solved]Can‘t use qemu:commandline with virt-manager

Tags: linux, qemu, virtualization, fixed, libvirt

Everytime I try to edit the xml file from my VM in virt-Manager and add the following line to the domain open tag xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'
And then try do something with qemu:commandline Tag and press Apply virt-manager doesn’t accept this and deletes these lines and I can‘t figure out why

I tried it with virt-xml, but this can‘t find the domain name and with —debugging on virt-manager I didn‘t get any clue.

EDIT: only works with virt-xml for more Information read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that question regarding this xml line has already been asked here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591252/libvirt-how-to-pass-qemu-command-line-args-now-libvirt-schemas-is-404

**virt-xml** does not detect the domain most likely because you are not connecting to the correct qemu URI

try adding **--connect** option to command

`virt-xml --connect qemu:///system`

Answer (score 0):

I Found now the solution, with the virt-xml command and with the —connect qemu:///system I could add the qemu:commandline tag und edit all tags within these tag, without any Problems. I don‘t know why it only worked with virt-xml and not if I edit the xml and put all those changes, but it work